# Focus cells in reverse order for any utility don't support RTL

Tags: delphi

**Focus cells in reverse order in DBGRID**

Some times I get some components that descendant from DBGRID, for some reason it is not support RTL, that guide me to think of change the behavior of tab key to appear that is support RTL, the only thing I need for that to change the direction of tab key.

I am sure that my question will help any user needing RTL (Like Hebrew and Arabic) for using some components that don't support RTL.

That Leading me to ask: how to change the keystroke action when keys are pressed to reverse action of the Tab key as follows:

- Tab key ---> Shift Tab;
- Shift Tab ---> Tab key;

Comment: What are you hoping for here. We provide code to convert this immense class to support RTL?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, the major demand is who to  make a control of keystroke events on a certain object (cxGrid) and how make a specific column like what we can do it in (dbgrid).

Comment: One question at a time please. Can you edit to ask just a single question.

Comment: Mr. David: can I change my question to: How to change Tab key behavior to Shift Tab and Shift Tab to Tab in Delphi? Please;

Comment: Why dont you ask the Vendor?

Comment: You can edit the question. This was explained in the various articles that you agreed to read when you signed up. To refresh your memory visit the [help]. Take the two minute tour. Then read the other articles.

Comment: I don't understand your reference to Tab and Shift-Tab.  In a cxGrid DBTableView, by default (on a new grid) they do the same thing, to toggle the focus on the current cell.  What are you hoping for them to do?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: you are right,  There is new version that support RTL, i notice it just right now, https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T340412.  Thanks. but still need answer of my last question for how to change tab behavior for knowledge.

Comment: @MartynA: I need to inverse the direction, when press tab i want to go the prior cell, shift-tab go the next cell.

Comment: But as I said, by default, they both toggle the focus on the current cell, they don't move the focus from one cell to another.  That's why I asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I am refresh now my memory, i reviewed help center. Thank you and accept my apologize for weak question, i'll try to be best in future.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes you are right, but I need to reverse direction. I need tab action as shift-tab action, and shift-tab action as tab action.

Comment: But the tab action has NO direction, so how can it be reversed?

Comment: The question edit narrows the focus but perhaps too far. Now we don't know what grid you refer to.

Comment: @MartynA: Let us say i am on second cell at first row, when I press tab it change focus to third cell at the same row, and when i press shift-tab it change focus to first cell at the same row. what i want if i press tab change focus to prior cell (first cell), and when i press shift-tab change focus to next cell (third cell).

Comment: It doesn't do that on a grid freshly added from the Component Palette with no settings changed, so what settings are you changing?

Comment: @MartynA: I want to change onkeyup, onkeydown, onkeypress events to implement what i want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I refer to normal dbgrid.

Comment: That information should appear in the question.

Comment: I try a code now it solve my problem, thanks to all.

Comment: Btw, I was talking about the Tab/Shift Tab action in a cxGrid, which is what you started off asking about.  It is not helpful to change your q so that it is asking about a component which behaves differently in the first place.

Comment: Other downvoters:  On reflection, I reversed my previous -1 because the Op's most recent edit turns it into an interesting q with a not-quite-straighforward answer.  Ymmv, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code, **without** an OnKeyUp handler, does what you seem to want

```
    type
      TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);

    procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift:
        TShiftState);
    begin
      if Key = VK_Tab then begin
        Key := 0;
        if ssShift in Shift then
          DBGrid1.SelectedIndex := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex + 1
        else begin
          if TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col = 1 then begin
            //  The following goes to the rightmost cell in the next row 
            //  if the focus is already on the leftmost column, as specified
            //  in the original version of the q
            DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
            TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).Col := DBGrid1.Columns.Count;
          end
          else
            DBGrid1.SelectedIndex := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex - 1;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

**Update**  In a comment to this, you asked for a fuller implementation.  Here it is:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift:
    TShiftState);

  procedure TabForwards;
  begin
    if TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col = DBGrid1.Columns.Count then begin
      DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
      if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Eof then
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Append;
      TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).Col := 1;
    end
    else
      DBGrid1.SelectedIndex := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex + 1;
  end;

  procedure TabBackwards;
  begin
    if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.State = dsInsert then begin
       DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Cancel;
       Exit;
    end;

    if TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Row = 1 then begin
      if TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col = 1 then
        TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col := DBGrid1.Columns.Count
      else
        DBGrid1.SelectedIndex := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex - 1;
    end
    else begin
      if TMyDBGrid(DBGrid1).Col = 1 then begin
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Prior;
        TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).Col := DBGrid1.Columns.Count;
      end
      else
        DBGrid1.SelectedIndex := DBGrid1.SelectedIndex - 1;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Caption := IntToStr(TMyDbGrid(DBGrid1).RowCount);
  if cbNormal.Checked then
    Exit;
  if Key = VK_Tab then begin
    Key := 0;
    if ssShift in Shift then
      TabForwards
    else
      TabBackwards;
  end;
end;
```

Notice that this uses `TabForwards` and `TabBackwards` sub-procedures and effectively reverses the roles of Tab and Shift Tab.  The reason for this is because it separates thinking, and talking, about the movement behaviour from the key combination which produces it, which I found easier easier to code and to describe what the movement behaviour actually is.

With Tab and Shift Tab behaving as standard, this is how the DBGrid behaves:

1. Tabbing forwards

If the cursor is in the New Record row, focus move to the next cell in the row until it reaches the RH column, then it wraps to the first column.

Otherwise, focus moves to the next cell in the current row until it reaches the RH column, then it wraps to the first column of the next row, if there is one, otherwise it calls Append on the grid's Dataset, and moves to the first column of the New Record row.

In the New Record row, pressing the Tab Backwards key abandons the new record.

2. Tabbing backwards

If the cursor is in the New Record row, the new record is abandoned.  Otherwise, focus moves to the prior cell in the current row until it reaches the LH column, then it wraps to the RH column of the prior row.  Once it reaches the LH column of the first row, it wraps to the RH column in that row.

That is what the second example does.

This does not, however, do what you said in your comment

> when I reach last cell in DBgrid, the tab key (not shift-Tab) need to open new record.

and this is why:

Your way, the behaviour of the grid in response to the Tab key is different in the last cell compared with every other one.  In the other cells, Tab will move left and wrap upwards to the prior row, whereas in the last cell it will move downwards.  That would puzzle me as a user.  Anyway, if that's really what you want, you can rearrange the second example to behave that way.

When you use Tab and Shift Tab in the normal way, the behaviour is as follows:

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Thanks.  This q has had a somewhat chequered history, as you may have seem from the comments, mixing up discussion of TcxGrid with TDBGrid.

Comment: @TomBrunberg;  Yes I did, thanks for spotting.  Fixed.

Comment: @MartynA: The code have bugs: 1) Normally when you reach last row it and press tab it open a new record, but in your code, the cursor is still at the end of dbgrid and does not open new record. 2) while continuous pressing tab it moving to next cell correctly but while continuous pressing Shift-Tab it reach to the rightmost cell and stay there.

Comment: @MarwanAlmukh: Both those are **not** bugs - they are simply limitations if the implementation I have given you in this example.  I was assuming you would be able to do the rest yourself.  They should both be trivial to implement - can you not see how?

Comment: @MartynA, Yes, can you till me who, Please, Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but as you are doing everything RTL, surely you want the new row to appear when you press Shift + Tab in the last cell?  If the cursor is on the RH cell of the last row, the user will be expecting tab to take him to the cell to the left of the last cell.

Comment: @MartynA, I mean that when I reach last cell in DBgrid, the tab key (not shift-Tab) need to open new record.  and the an other thing when I press (shift-tab) continuously still given an action what expected not like your current code.

Comment: @MartynA; Very Nice code and expert.. Please make a look of my new solution (I think its shorter).